# Can I show the EmptyDataTemplate manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

Simple question here:

Can I show the EmptyDataTemplate of an asp.net ListView dynamically and manually from code behind (C#)?

thanks in advance!

Comment: and the question is why?

Comment: because the listview is basically never empty, even if it has no data. I fill it up with an objectdatasource, which always returns data. Ofc its possible to just return no data to the listview but it would be a big effort in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind i edited my ObjectDataSource which always returned data. Now it only returns data if data exists. In my case this is pretty unlovely so if someone has an answer to my question i would be very happy.